# SQL trigger not working

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers, plpgsql

```
CREATE TABLE lab7.standings
(
    team_name    VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    wins         INTEGER,
    losses       INTEGER,
    winPct       NUMERIC,
    CHECK(wins > 0),
    CHECK(losses >0)
);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION
calc_winning_percentage()
RETURNS trigger AS $$
BEGIN
    New.winPct := New.wins /(New.wins + New.losses);
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$$LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER
update_winning_percentage
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON standings
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE calc_winning_percentage();
```

This is accurately updating the wins in my standings table, but doesn't seem to send my new calculated winning percentage.

Comment: Table definition with *exact* column names? Any other triggers or rules on the table?

Comment: CREATE TABLE standings
(
        team_name       VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
        wins            INTEGER,
        losses          INTEGER,
        winPct NUMERIC,
        CHECK(wins > 0),
        CHECK(losses >0)

);

Comment: Please **edit** your question. Essential information should not be hidden in comments.

Comment: Detail (not relevant to the question): Why do you have the `>0` checks? Shouldn't they be `>=0`? I'm sure there can be teams with only wins or only losses, right?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_winning_percentage
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON standings
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE calc_winning_percentage();
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to changing the trigger to `BEFORE` like [pointed out by @Grijesh](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15453483/939860):

I notice *three* things in your table definition:

#### 1.`integer` vs. `numeric`

`wins` and `losses` are of type [**`integer`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-numeric.html), but `winPct` is [**`numeric`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-numeric.html).

Try the following:

```
SELECT 1 / 4, 2 / 4
```

Gives you `0` both times. The result is of type `integer`, fractional digits are **truncated towards zero**. This happens in your trigger function *before* the `integer` result is coerced to `numeric` in the assignment. Therefore, changes in `wins` and `losses` that only affect fractional digits are lost to the result. Fix this by:

.. either changing the **column definition** to `numeric` for all involved columns in the base table.
.. or changing the trigger function:

```
NEW.winPct := NEW.wins::numeric / (NEW.wins + NEW.losses);
```

Casting one of the numbers in the calculation to `numeric` (`::numeric`) forces the result to be `numeric` and preserves fractional digits.

I **strongly suggest** the *second* variant, since `integer` is obviously the right type for `wins` and `losses`. If your percentage doesn't have to be super-exact, I would also consider using a plain [*floating point type* (`real` or `double precision`)](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-numeric.html) for the percentage. Your trigger could then use:

```
NEW.winPct := NEW.wins::float8 / (NEW.wins + NEW.losses);
```

#### 2.The unquoted column name `winPct`

It's cast to lower case and effectively just `winpct`. Be sure to read about [identifiers in PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS).

#### 3. Schema

Your table obviously lives in a non-standard schema: `lab7.standings`. Unless that is included in your `search_path`, the trigger creation has to use a schema-qualified name:

```
...
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON lab7.standings
...
```

#### P.S.

Goes to show the importance of posting your table definition with this kind of question.

Comment: @RyanHaslag: Would be better to leave `wins` and `losses` as `integer`. Consider the recommendations I added to my answer.